# Improving Dynamo DB response time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following Dynamo DB table structure:

- item_type (string)  --> **Partition Key**
- item_id (number) --> **Secondary Index**

The table has around 5 million records and auto scaling is enabled with default read capacity of 5. I need to fetch the item_id given certain item type. We have around 500000 item_types and each item type will be associated with multiple item ids. I see a response of around 4 seconds for popular item_types. I am testing this on AWS Lambda, I start the timer when we make the query and end it once we get the response. Both Lambda and Dynamo DB are in the same region.

This is the query I am using:

```
response = items_table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('item_type').eq(search_term),
    ProjectionExpression='item_id'
)
```

Following are some of the observations:

- It takes more time to fetch popular items
- As the number of records increase, the response time increases

I have tried Dynamo DB Cache but the Python SDK is not up to the mark and it has certain limitations.

Given these details following are the questions:

- Why is the response time so high? Is it because I am querying on a string not a number.
- Increasing the read capacity also did not help but why?
- Is there any other aws service which is faster than Dynamo DB for such type of queries.

I have seen seminars where they claim to get sub millisecond response times on billions of records with multiple users accessing the table. Any pointers towards achieving sub second response time will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: does it take as long when you use the console ? maybe it has something to do with lambda?

Comment: Temporarily, increase the amount of memory allocated to the Lambda function to a large value, and see if this changes the behavior.  This has a side effect of giving you a larger CPU slice and can identify situations where your performance is actually constrained by the CPU demands of your code.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I tried giving it maximum memory, no change in response time. What is the best way to test the true response time of my dynamo db queries?

Comment: @user3277530 yes it does. I'll try to post the statistics but the response times are high in either case. Is the issue with the table structure since I have both partition key and secondary index.

Comment: does it take also around 4 seconds for non popular items ? if not then I think you are having hot keys problems

Comment: @user3277530 no it is much lesser for non popular items, even sub seconds in some cases. How do I avoid the hot keys issue in this particular case. Because the input I receive is the item type and hence I created the partition key as the item_type. Is there a different way to design this table. I can put all the item_ids in an array but that would make it difficult to maintain the table.